# Django: Validator for a multiple choice form field

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, python-2.7

I have a multiple choice field in my form where users are given a list of fields, and they can select a maximum of three choices. I've defined a custom validator for restricting users from selecting more than three fields.

forms.py

```
class EvangelizedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    area_of_interest = forms.CharField(
        max_length=1230,
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(
            choices=Evangelized.AREA_CHOICES),
        help_text="Areas of interest(Upto 3)")
```

I have defined a custom form validator named `len_area` in models.py as follows:

```
def len_area(li):
    if len(li) > 3:
        raise ValidationError("Please select a maximum of three fields only")
```

models.py

```
class Evangelized(models.Model):
    AREA_CHOICES = (
        ('Govt', 'Govt'),
        ('Entertainment', 'Entertainment'),
        ('Automobile', 'Automobile'),
        ('Careers', 'Careers'),
        ('Books','Books'),
        ('Family', 'Family'),
        ('Food', 'Food'),
        ('Gaming', 'Gaming'),
        ('Beauty', 'Beauty'),
        ('Sports','Sports'),
        ('Events', 'Events'),
        ('Business', 'Business'),
        ('Travel', 'Travel'),
        ('Health', 'Health'),
        ('Technology','Technology'),
    ) 
    area_of_interest = models.CharField(
        max_length=1280,
        validators=[len_area])
```

However, the `ValidationError` message gets thrown at the user at all times, i.e even when the selected fields are three or less than three.

What seems to be wrong with my validator function?

Comment: Try printing the arguments for your validator, I've got the feeling that you'll find the problem in there :)

Comment: To use the `CheckboxSelectMultipleField` you probably want to use a `forms.MultipleChoiceField` btw, I don't think it works properly with a `CharField`

Comment: @Wolph I tried printing the argument. So when the user selects two fields, then the argument passed to the validator is `[u'abc', u'xyz']`, the length of which is two. Hence, shouldn't the validator work in this case and not throw a `ValidationError`?

Comment: Yes... seems valid indeed. Doesn't really make sense, are you sure you're looking at the correct `ValidationError`?

Comment: @Wolph I tried printing the length of each argument passed, and strangely, the argument passed is the total number of characters in `[u'abc', u'xyz']`, instead of passing the length of the total number of elements inside the list.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that value, returned by `CheckboxSelectMultiple`'s `value_from_datadict` method, is list `[u'abc', u'xyz']`. Then it is converted to string `[u'abc', u'xyz']` by field's `to_python` method (actually, it is `u"[u'abc', u'xyz']"`). After validators are run. Length of this string is more than 3, that's why you got `ValidationError`.

You should use `ManyToManyField`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my validator wasn't working as intended was because the argument passed to the validator, say `[u'abc', u'xyz']`, was a string and not a list as I earlier thought while defining my validator. As a result, as rightly pointed out by @f43d65, the length of the argument exceeded 3 every single time, and hence the `ValidationError` was being raised.

I made the following changes in my validator in order for it to work as intended:

```
def len_area(li):
    if li.count("u'") > 3:
        raise ValidationError("Please select a maximum of three fields only")
```

Comment: String, that will be stored in the model, will be `[u'abc', u'xyz']` in this case.

Comment: That's a bad solution imho, if you somehow have a word that ends with `u` it will be counted twice. Assuming you want everything stored as a comma separated list anyhow, why not modify the `clean_area_of_interest` method?

Comment: @Wolph I agree. Probably not the best solution in this case. I will look into modifying the `clean_area_of_interest` method now. Thanks.